# Android Studio: How to disable updates for just core platform version?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Our project uses Android Studio 2.2 .  Upgrading to 2.3 would force us to update our IDE config , which we are not ready to do at the moment.  Every time I start the IDE, I have that pop-up.  Once I mistook the pop-up for an SDK update, clicked it, and then had to reinstall 2.2.  With all the steps and 15+ minutes it took to bring things back, this proved to be an unhappy distraction.

So I'm aware in `Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior > System settings > Updates` I can disable all updates. However that's not a solution for my requirements - because I want the updates for all other components like SDK, etc.

Is there a way to disable updates for just core platform version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to `Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior > System settings > Notifications`
2. Select from **Popup** dropdown to mute the alert

[image]